# Issues connecting to Cloud SQL using cloudsql-proxy via Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a cluster with 3 pods. In each pod I have 2 containers. **app** which is a front end Django project and **cloudsql-proxy** I have followed all of the guides and I can connect to the database via the cloudsql-proxy from my computer.

However I have issues when in my container is connecting. I see this error on the cloudsql-proxy container when it receives new connections:

> 2018/05/01 13:45:50 Listening on 127.0.0.1:5432 for projectname-11111:europe-west1:projectname
>   2018/05/01 13:45:50 Ready for new connections
>   2018/05/01 13:46:40 New connection for "projectname-11111:europe-west1:projectname"
>   2018/05/01 13:46:40 couldn't connect to "projectname-11111:europe-west1:projectname": Post https://www.googleapis.com/sql/v1beta4/projects/projectname-201611/instances/projectname/createEphemeral?alt=json: private key should be a PEM or plain PKSC1 or PKCS8; parse error: asn1: syntax error: sequence truncated

Can anyone assist with this? - It looks pretty straight forward that the problem is with the key in the JSON. But I just don't understand why there would be as this was generated when creating the service account.

Here is the Json file which has been obfuscated:

```
{
"type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "projectname-11111",
  "private_key_id": "id",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nkeykeykey==\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "email@projectname-11111.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "123456789",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/circleci-deployment%40projectname-11111.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
}
```

Comment: Can you describe how have you created the json file? Can you paste it here (removing all sensitive information)?

Comment: @suren I have added t the main question. They key was created by Google when the service account was set up and downloaded directly when I "Furnished" the key.

Comment: Seems to be right. Can you check if you have "Cloud SQL Admin API" enabled, and your service account has "Cloud SQL Client" role assigned? If yes, can you share the yaml files you use? I will reproduce the issue.

Comment: I have figured it. I deleted the service account and re-created. Furnished a new Key and everything is ok. It must have been malformed.